# Typescrypt and Angular: File.separator analogue

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string which can be with "/" or "\" inside, depending on the OS (windows or Linux) default file separator.

In java I have File.separator to automatically retrieve the correct character depending on the machine.

How can I do that in Typescript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Path.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path)

```
path.parse('/home/user/dir/file.txt');
path.parse('C:\\path\\dir\\file.txt');
```

**Edit: For joining paths:*

```
path.join('foo/', 'bar', 'baz' );
path.join('C:\\foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: No, I do not have to parse a path, but build one and add / or \ automatically based on the platform behind

Comment: Also Path.normalize(path) is useful